Send push notification to Android device with PHP
I'm trying to figure out how to send push notification to Android devices with PHP.
I've looked it up on multiple sites and this is the last what I've tried:
function sendFCM($registrationIds, $notifTitle, $notifDesc, $notifChannel, $data) {

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('bla.json');
    $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging');
    $client->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
    $token = $client->getAccessToken();
    $accessToken = $token['access_token'];

    $headers = array (
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type:application/json'
    );

    $notification = array
    (
        "title" => $notifTitle, 
        "body" => $notifDesc, 
        "icon" => "ic_logo_circle",
        "android_channel_id" => $notifChannel
    );

    $fields = array
    (
        'notification' => $notification, 
        'data' => $data, 
        'registration_ids' => $registrationIds
    );      

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectname/messages:send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    print($result);

    curl_close($ch);
}

$notifData = array( 
    "title" => "this is the title",
    "msg" => "the desc",
    "image" => "whatever.jpg"
);

sendFCM($registrationIds, "Antwort auf Kommentar", "Cornholio hat dir geantwortet", "channel_reply_comment", $notifData);

$registrationIds contains array of multiple Android device tokens

{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "notification": Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "data": Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "registration_ids": Cannot find field.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "details": [ { "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest", "fieldViolations": [ { "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "notification": Cannot find field." }, { "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "data": Cannot find field." }, { "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "registration_ids": Cannot find field." } ] } ] } }


The FCM v1 API doesn't expect a registration_ids field. You'll want to the tokens field instead.
For this and more, keep the documentation on sending messages handy

Ok based on the link you've provided I did:     $fields = [
'message' => [
'token' => 'xxxxxx',
'notification' => [
'title' => $notifTitle,
'body' => $notifDesc
]
]
];  and it worked, thanks. But it doesn't work when I pass an array of tokens, which worked with the old way of sendin push mess.. an you show how to send to array of tokens?

From the same doc: "The batch send methods described in this section were deprecated on June 21, 2023, and will be removed in June 2024. For protocol, instead use the standard HTTP v1 API send method, implementing your own batch send by iterating through the list of recipients and sending to each recipient's token. For Admin SDK methods, make sure to update to the next major version. See the Firebase FAQ for more information." If you have more questions about this, please post a new question.
